# Is the "Lookup in Dictionary" context menu option hardcoded in Google Chrome for Mac?

Tags: google-chrome, services

I'm having a hard time removing the "Lookup in Dictionary" context menu element in Chrome for Mac (see screenshot).

[image: Chrome's context menu]

I tried deactivating the Dictionary Service shortcut in Preferences / Keyboard, and I also tweaked Dictionary.app's `Info.plist` to remove the service. I even removed the entire Dictionary app, but the context menu item still shows. Might it be hard coded into Chrome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing are the OSX built in Text Services, such as Spelling and auto-correct services when dealing with anything in OSX that is text.

These services are automatic for the whole OS and cannot be turned off and are available in every application

Note: Spelling Auto-Correct can be turned off/managed in System Preferences -> Languages & Text -> Text

The "Services Manager" and the "Dictionary Service" only relate to what is shown and provided in the Services Menu within running applications.  you can turn off those within (oddly enough) System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Services

Comment: Well, they don't show up in Firefox, for example... as in lots of other apps. And I don't think spelling auto-correct has any impact on this.

Comment: Firefox has it turned off, the context menus are specific to Firefox not OSX.  Obviously the Chrome developers are using NSTextView and Firefox is not.

Comment: So I guess I'm stuck with those context menu items no matter what I do then? Unless I fork Chromium and stop using NSTextView?

Comment: that is my belief, yes.

Comment: It's probably not worth it then. Thx!