# How to disable "look up" context menu in Google Chrome OSX 10.10+?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, contextual-menu

This is a distinct question from [Is the "Lookup in Dictionary" context menu option hardcoded in Google Chrome for Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37566/is-the-lookup-in-dictionary-context-menu-option-hardcoded-in-google-chrome-for)

I want to get rid of the "Look Up x" contextual menu in Chrome:

How can it be done?

[image]

Comment: This has been discussed in the Chrome development under this bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543891 but they opted to keep it to not "break the Mac UI feel". They are apparently looking into some instrumentation to see if it is used at all (I bet the answer is no) before considering removing it. An option to get rid of it would be enough if you ask me.

Comment: This is so annoying, i misclick it so many times when trying to copy some text. It would already help if this would be moved further down the context menu.

Comment: BTW... which tool did you use to edit the screenshot?

Comment: Skitch.........

Comment: "Lookup on <Google>" or "Lookup on <Preferred Reference Site>" would be a much better solution.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543891 remains open, as of 2021. Please considering starring the issue on that site if you think this is important.

Comment: It would be useful to include a link to a means to disable this menu item across MacOS (not only specific to chrome).  I believe that would solve the concern of the poster.

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately it cannot be removed. It was marked as WontFix because it's part of the MacOS convention. It has been officially answered here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543891

Comment: To be specific, it is mac os convention but they populate the menu item themselves. But you cannot get rid of it in other apps either, so allowing to remove it in chrome would thus technically be breaking convention. If you want to get rid of it, you can either get some chrome fork to implement a patch for this, or monkeypatch it at runtime by swizzling NSMenu

Comment: And so the appropriate solution would be something in MacOS settings that allowed us to turn it off everywhere.  This isn't really a Chrome specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not really answer as much as workaround: Lean on `Command-C`.

I like the "*rapid dictionary*" feature. When 95% certain I'm about to use a word correctly, confirming is faster than opening a new tab to type `dictionary.com/browse/X`.

I'd be interested in hearing why you (OP, @aaronbauman) dislike it.  Maybe adding your name will flag you to respond.

---

This answer is nearly three years old--haven't used Mac for awhile, don't recall my mindset at the time. But re-reading suggests I got more of a "copy" impression from the question that I get from it now.  Edited for brevity.

Comment: Please consider that your "answer" will be read by millions. It needs to be short, concise, on topic. Not your entire boring biography.

Comment: @DirkBester umm... thanks I guess? You're not wrong, but a simple "please remain on topic" would also have worked. Updated.

Comment: PS: Question is approaching four years old and has only 6k views. I hope I haven't quite wasted the lives of millions just yet. :,)

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn't what you want to hear, but maybe you should switch to command + c to copy if you want to avoid it. Thats what I migrated to and I almost forgot "Look Up" was even there. It'll eventually become a reflex.

Comment: What's the relevance of Command+C? The menu has loads of other items. The one I normally use is "Search Google for ..." which searches fast and properly, as opposed to "Lookup" which searches (very slowly) the using the rubbish Mac engine.

Comment: Then add another hotkey? It shouldn't be too difficult with a small google search @mjaggard